# Can SWFs containing AS3 code be dynamically loaded on iOS?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Prior to Flash Player 11.6, SWFs containing ActionScript 3 code could not be loaded at runtime. The release notes say that multiple SWFs are now supported on iOS in AOT mode, starting with Flash Player 11.6. Are these SWFs able to contain AS3 code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where you want to load them from. If you package them in your app, you will be ok, because AIR (from version 3.6) will [cross-compile those swfs too.](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/)  
If you want to load them at runtime, you can do that with AIR 3.7 with the following restriction (from the [AIR 3.7 release notes (pdf)](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/shared/air3-7_flashplayer11-7_releasenotes.pdf)):

> During IPA packaging, ADT extracts the Actionscript code from all child SWFs which are specified within the sample text file, adds it to the final executable and moves the stripped SWFs into the "externalStrippedSwfs" folder created in the current working directory. The directory structure within the "externalStrippedSwfs" folder remains the same as specified within the text file. The generated stripped SWF's can be externally hosted on a web server of developer's choice.

I have no experience with this because I think it's not really worth the hassle if you can only load swfs without code after all.